# PostThreadMessage to background thread fails

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi

I am trying to send a message from the main thread to background one in C# wpf.

Background thread is the following:

```
        public class LoopThread()
        {
            public void Start()
            {
                User32.MSG msg;
                sbyte ret;
                while(true)
                {
                    ret = User32.GetMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0);
                    //Here the debugger never reaches
                    ......
                }
            }
        }
```

And the Main thread:

```
            LoopThread loop = new LoopThread();
            Thread threadLoop = new Thread(loop.Start);
            threadLoop.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(100);

            bool postResult = User32.PostThreadMessage(
                Convert.ToUInt32(threadLoop.ManagedThreadId),
                WM_USER + 1,
                UIntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero);
```

But `postResult == false`. And `GetLastWin32Error` returns `ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID`.

So, where is the mistake?

Comment: You need to post it to the Win32 thread ID. The `ManagedThreadId` is not the same thing. In any case why are you doing this at all? Why don't you use the buily in .net mechanisms to queue messages/events onto different threads?

Comment: @HristoIliev That's a bit mean spirited. It's easy to miss documentation. Not everyone knows everything inside out. Otherwise SO would not exist. Anyway, if we know that our host is a simple managed beast, then I guess there is a fixed relationship between managed and unmanaged threads.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the text is put in a clearly visible box on the main page of the documentation of the `Thread` class, not hidden deeply on some obscure page. SO is about solving problems, not about creating a copy of one or another documentation projects. Anyway, if the relationship is known to be fixed, you can have the thread call the Win32 [GetCurrentThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and store the identifier somewhere.